# Not able to enter card number using Send keys,JavaScript Executor and Action Class

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am trying to enter the stripe card details . It does not enter card number. I am able to click but sendkeys or javascript executor and action class throw no such window exception. But I am able to enter date and CVC..This card detail is a frame. I am already switching to frame before entering the detail.

[image]
[image]

```
public void enterCardDetails() throws InterruptedException {
          
       cardNumberStripe.click();
       cardNumberStripe.clear();
       cardNumberStripe.sendKeys("4242424242424242");
    
        dateStripe.sendKeys("08/23");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        cardVerificationNumberStripe.sendKeys("123");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        zipCodeStripe.sendKeys("1000");
   }
```

JsExecutor code that I tried

```
JavascriptExecutor user=  (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
user.executeScript("arguments[0].value='4242424242424242'",cardNumberStripe);
```

chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39
( chrome=84.0.4147.135)
java.version: '1.8.0_261'

Comment: How do you get the card number element? Maybe you have the wrong element. For example in your screenshot you show the placeholder label selected instead of the textbox.

Comment: Can you show us the selector for **dateStripe** and **cardVerificationNumberStripe**.

Comment: @DilipMeghwal  ... Below are the Selectors   @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@placeholder='Card number']")
 WebElement cardNumberStripe;
 
 @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@placeholder='MM / YY']")
 WebElement dateStripe;
 
 @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@placeholder='CVC']")
 WebElement cardVerificationNumberStripe;

Comment: All locators are correct, can you update the question with exact error logs.

Comment: Things look good, even the JSExecutor should work fine.. looks like some issue with location the element, Exact error will be appreciated.

Comment: @all...Now I am able to enter card number..  I just put code like cardNumberStripe.Sendkeys("4242 4242 4242 4242"); cardNumberStripe.clear(); cardNumberStripe.Sendkeys("4242 4242 4242 4242");